# The error I get is Mismatch type on the line 'If lineod<>"" then'

Tags: excel, vba, userform

```
Private Sub cmd_autoassign_search_Click()
Dim inputod As Double
inputod = Me.tb_pipe_ID_autoassign.Text
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ptf As Worksheet
Set ptf = wb.Sheets("PTF")
If inputod <> "" Then

With tb_sizeA
.Value = CDbl(Application.VLookup(inputod, ptf.Range("B8:D47"), 2, 0))
End With
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't compare a `Double` to `""`.

Comment: Thank you for being prompt. Can you please edit my code? I am very new to VBA Coding.

Comment: Am still getting the same error. Private Sub cmd_autoassign_search_Click()
Dim sizea As Double
Dim inputod As Double
inputod = Me.tb_pipe_ID_autoassign.Value
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ptf As Worksheet
Set ptf = wb.Sheets("PTF")
If tb_pipe_ID_autoassign.Value <> "" Then
sizea = Application.VLookup(inputod, ptf.Range("B8:D47"), 2, 0)
tb_sizeA.Text = sizea
Else
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Private Sub cmd_autoassign_search_Click()

    Dim inputod , v ' <<< As Variant...
    
    inputod = Me.tb_pipe_ID_autoassign.Text

    If Len(inputod) > 0 And Isnumeric(inputod) Then
    
        v = Application.VLookup(CDbl(inputod), _
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PTF").Range("B8:D47"), 2, False)

        tb_sizeA.Value = IIf(IsError(v), "", v) 'Check for no match
    Else
        tb_sizeA.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But it still throwing an error. Says 'Wrong number of arguments or Invalid property assignment'. Highlights the 'IIF(IsError(v,"",v)' code.

Comment: Hello Tim. Still no luck with the code. But thanks man!